# How do I export & import files between Android devices and Windows OS?

Tags: windows, file-transfer

How do I export and import binary files between Android devices and Windows OS as well as syncing the files between the two?

Answer (score 4):

You can connect the device to the PC with a USB cable and access it via Explorer in the same way that you would a thumb drive.  In addition, I like using [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) to sync files in a wireless fashion.  I find this to be much easier and does not restrict movement of handset.

Answer (score 3):

You mean Desktop Windows, right? If you are using Eclipse, you can *pull/push* files using the DDMS perspective.

You can also use the command-line tools to accomplish the same. Have a look at [Stack Overflow - Moving files to SDcard on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530901/android-sdcard-question).

Answer (score 2):

Installing new apps can be done using `adb` tool from the Android SDK:

```
platform-tools\adb.exe install abc.apk
```

Same for downloading files:

```
platform-tools\adb.exe pull /sdcard/filexyz
```

Or you use a GUI for ADB like [DroidExplorer](https://github.com/camalot/droidexplorer).

Via WLAN you can use software that shares the Android file system via HTTP or FTP. For example, if you use [SwiFTP](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.swiftp) and change the shared folder from `/sdcard` to `/` you can access every file on the phone.

A connection via ADB is also possible in case you have a rooted phone - eg. via [ADB wireless](https://market.android.com/search?q=adb%20wireless&so=1&c=apps).